# Utility like iFinBox and iExplorer for OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsfilewrapper

I want to make a Utility app like [iFunBox](http://i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/) and [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) for Mac OS X where i can retrieve information and files of connected device and display it.

Though i have good experience in iPhone Development, I have never developed anything for mac.Can anybody provide me good starting point from where i can start.

Thanks

Comment: Start here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/

Comment: Thanks Paul ...I really want to know underline API that is used by this softwares ... so i can start exploring them  directly

Comment: All the API info is available at the link above.

Comment: @PaulR Your comment seems pretty useless to me. Almost all questions on SO can be answered by posting the above link. This does not mean just giving out the link is a good answer...

Comment: @Christian: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that questions here can have comments as well as answers. While answers are expected to provide a solution to the posted questions, comments are simply for suggestions or for for requesting clarification. This particular question has no answers as yet (probably because it's too broad and/or shows no sign of any research effort) but my comment above was intended to steer the questioner in an appropriate direction, i.e. reading the Mac OS X developer documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a public API from Apple for working directly with iOS devices. There are open source solutions like [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org) if you want to make an iFunBox style application.